# Permission denied for postgis options

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psql, postgis-raster

I'm thinking of how I can implement out-DB rasters in pgAdmin. When I went over the documentation provided [here](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Creating_Rasters), I was stumped at the part where it tells me to
`SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = true; SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers TO 'ENABLE_ALL';`

When I typed this in my psql shell, it says ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers"
I am logged in with rds_superuser priveleges. Can someone tell me how to grant my user this permission?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters can only be changed by a superuser:

```
SELECT name, context FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE 'postgis%';

             name             │  context  
══════════════════════════════╪═══════════
 postgis.enable_outdb_rasters │ superuser
 postgis.gdal_datapath        │ superuser
 postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers │ superuser
 postgis.gdal_vsi_options     │ user
(4 rows)
```

Now you are not using PostgreSQL, but an unspecified Amazon fork of it. So you don't get superuser access (`rds_superuser` is not a superuser).

Your only option is to change the parameter globally, by using the interface that Amazon provides for changing database parameters.

Comment: I checked t he parameter groups in AWS, but postgis.enable_outdb_rasters is not included as a modifable parameter. Do you know of any other way around this?

Comment: There is none. Don't use a hosted database, then this is no problem.